# Why does this azure function produce a JSON output?

Tags: c#, json, azure, azure-functions

I am following a tutorial for creating an Azure app, part of which cleans up the html from the body of an email: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/tutorial-process-email-attachments-workflow#create-function-to-clean-html

The relevant section is as follows:

```cs
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log) {

   log.LogInformation("HttpWebhook triggered");

   // Parse query parameter
   string emailBodyContent = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

   // Replace HTML with other characters
   string updatedBody = Regex.Replace(emailBodyContent, "<.*?>", string.Empty);
   updatedBody = updatedBody.Replace("\\r\\n", " ");
   updatedBody = updatedBody.Replace(@"&nbsp;", " ");

   // Return cleaned text
   return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult(new { updatedBody });
}
```

The following test input: `{"name": "<p><p>Testing my function</br></p></p>"}`

is expected to give the following output: `{"updatedBody":"{\"name\": \"Testing my function\"}"}`

**Why is the output wrapped in {"updatedBody":} json?**

As far as I can see from looking at the code, the output is provided as a string array, using an object called updatedBody to populate the only element in the array (`return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult(new { updatedBody });`) - but it looks like instead the `{ updatedBody }` is treated as a json array somehow?

Comment: Because you have an object with a property called `updatedBody`?

Comment: Humor me, instead of using an anonymous object inside `OkObjectResult`, try passing in `updatedBody` directly.

Comment: Then you get `{ {"name": "Testing my function"}}`

Comment: So what do you want? An explanation why your c# property makes a JSON property, or the wrapping property removed? And what you just posted isn't valid JSON.

Comment: I want an explanation of what it is in the function that makes the function treat the output as JSON

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/quickly-create-json-object

Comment: but in that link they deliberately serialize to json, which doesn't (explicitly) happen anywhere in the code I've given. to make it clearer, an input of `test` gives an output of `{"updatedBody":"test"}`. Perhaps the import of `using Newtonsoft.Json;` (which I don't see used anywhere) is relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter of `OkObjectResult` is an `object`. That class is responsible (along with the underlying azure function / asp.net core pipeline) for serializing that data into a string, and adding it to the HTTP response content. (There are some special cases like when the data you pass in is a `string`, but that's not important now)

The serialization is done for you *after* the method has concluded. You don't need to worry about it. The framework takes care of it.

That's why your JSON has a wrapped "updatedBody" property. If I have the following code:

```cs
string myValue = "yes";
return OkObjectResult(new {
  myValue
});
```

I'd get the following JSON

```json
{
  "myValue": "yes"
}
```

You can change the property name as well

```cs
string myValue = "yes";
return OkObjectResult(new {
  message = myValue
});
```

```json
{
  "message": "yes"
}
```

This is how JSON.Net (the c# library) and Microsoft's System.Text.Json libraries work, and OkObjectResult uses this behind the scenes.